# Measuring distance to two Points in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point, geometry, typecast

I would like to know how to measure the distance from two Points in ArcPy?

I know only Geometry has the distanceTo method but how do I could make a typecast in ArcPy?

I got the following error message:

---

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'distanceTo'
```

Here is my code:

```
'''

... ptIni = {}
... ptEnd = {}
... for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("polilinha"):
...     ptIni = row.Shape.firstPoint
...     ptEnd = row.Shape.lastPoint
... print ptIni.distanceTo(ptFim)
```

Comment: You have a polyline and what to know the distance from first to last Point measured as a straight line (not along the line)?

Comment: The last version of ArcGIS that *didn't* support Data Access cursors is now long retired, so it's time to start actively discouraging the use of the less-than-Pythonic `arcpy.SearchCursor`. Instead, use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`, which is both faster and easier to integrate into Python list operators. If you read the doc on `firstPoint/lastPoint`, you'll see the result type is `Point`, but that `distanceTo` is an operation of `PointGeometry`. Be careful to retrieve the `SpatialReference` of the source layer and apply it to the `PointGeometry` constructor or the precision could be lost.

Comment: Point doesn't have distanceTo. **pointGeometry** does.

Comment: @BERA actually I need to find the walfway point by measuring distances between polyline parts (path).

Comment: @BERA I really want to make some coding without using the _positionAlongLine_ method to calculate the **midpoint** of a polyline.

Comment: Why? That is what the method is designed to do

Comment: I know but I questioned to the Javascript community and they didn't have no answere (the Javascript API doesn't have this call also). :-(

Comment: I would like to do it so in Arcpy and so in ArcGIS Javascript API

Comment: You've changed this question in comments enough to break the answer, and now the answer doesn't address the question. Please [Edit] the Question to ask the question you want answered. If you have a new question, you can ask it as a separate Question.

Comment: Since there is an answer it's too late to change this question from Python to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Use the da.SearchCursor instead of the old cursor.

To find mid point use positionAlongLine with `use_percentage=True`:

```
import arcpy
fc = 'Roads'
geom = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'SHAPE@')][0]
midpoint = geom.positionAlongLine(value=0.5, use_percentage=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I know this method but I would like to make the same without using the built-in feature.